# Section style in LaTeX

Tags: titlesec

In LaTeX, the code:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\centering\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
{SECTION \thesection}{14pt}{\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

produces the output of:

> SECTION 1   INTRODUCTION

I want the "INTRODUCTION" to be on a new line, but still part of the section tag, e.g.

> SECTION 1
>
> INTRODUCTION

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where do you want the `INTRODUCTION` part to be? Directly underneath etc, could you clarify where you want it to be please. This is how my current code looks: https://imgur.com/PuKUKD7

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `[display]` as the *shape* parameter. A list can be found on page 3 in the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). Then, the *space* parameter (`14pt` in your code) becomes vertical. Note that in two example below I am using `\filcenter` instead of `\centering` or `\raggedright` etc., which is explained in section *3.3 Spacing related tools*.

---

Example 1: both parts of the section are centred

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}{SECTION \thesection}{14pt}{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to something}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Example 2: only the title part is centred (the rest of the code is the same):

```latex
% ...
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{SECTION \thesection}{14pt}{\filcenter\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}
% ...
```

[image]

---

I would also suggest to read through a significant number of examples starting from page 20 (Appendix). It will help with understanding how this package works.